# jpa hibernate one-to-many bidirectional

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, bidirectional

I have an issue with one of my One-To-Many relationships.
My problem is when I add a Tenant into an Apartment it doesn't set the column value in the Tenant to the ApartmentID. The thing is I have the exact same relationship with other classes and they are working fine... Does anyone have an idea why it's not wotking?
Thanks

Apartment :

```
@Entity
public class Apartment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ApartmentID",unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int apartmentID;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "apartment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Tenant> tenants;
}
```

Tenant :

```
@Entity
public class Tenant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="TenantID",unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int tenantID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ApartmentID")
    private Apartment apartment;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your bi-directional relationship `Tenant` is the owner of the relationship. Since you are persisting `Apartment` you have to manually set the **apartment** of **tenant**.  If you want to get rid of manual setting change your `@OneToMany` as follows:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="ApartmentID",referencedColumnName="ApartmentID")
private List<Tenant> tenants;
```

By the way, with your current sample if you are persisting **tenant** with **apartment**; **apartment** will be automatically persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show all your code here. So that i'm not sure to get your issues exactly. However, i just follow the post [Hibernate Many to One Bidirectional Mapping Annotation Example](http://javabycode.com/java-frameworks/hibernate-4-tutorial/hibernate-many-to-one-bidirectional-mapping-annotation-example.html) and build project with your entities.

Here is main class that i add a Tenant into an Apartment.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
        Apartment apartment = new Apartment();
        tenant.setApartment(apartment);
        List<Tenant> tenants = new ArrayList<Tenant>();
        tenants.add(tenant);
        apartment.setTenants(tenants);

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(apartment);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
    }
```

Hibernate configuration

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">javabycode</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mypassword</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabycode</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>                
        <property name="format_sql">false</property>
        <mapping class="com.javabycode.hibernate.model.Tenant"/>
        <mapping class="com.javabycode.hibernate.model.Apartment"/>        
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Hibernate Util:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Session Factory could not be created." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

It's work fine! The ApartmentID is already assigned a value in Tanent table.

Comment: The thing is that you are setting the value to each side and I don't want to do that. If I do apartment.setTenants() and persist/merge it I should have the tenant updated with the apartment in its field but I don't. What's weird here is that I also have Housing and Landlord which has a one to many relationship and it's working flawlessly.
I can add pastebins of my models if you want but I'm sure that everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

```
**please refer the example you will get an idea**

--------------------------------------------------------

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String street;
    private int houseNumber;
    private String city;
    private int zipCode;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Person person;
}
```